# SQLiteOpenHelper does not install database file from assets

Tags: java, android, sqliteopenhelper

When the application installs, instead of copying the database file from Assets/databases and installing it into the application directory on the device, is is creating an empty database with the same name specified in the DBHelper class.

The Sqlite file that is created has the same name, but it only contains one table called android_metadata with row called android_metadata. I know this because i retrieved the file using Device Monitor.

Everything was working fine before, the db from assets was getting installed automatically then suddenly this began to happen.

DBHelper:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String TAG = "DBHelper";
private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.borehog.express.bhexpress/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "BHMock.db";
private static int DB_VERSION = 1;

private static DBHelper db;
private static Context context;

/**
 * Constructor should be private to prevent direct instantiation.
 * Make a call to the static method "getInstance()" instead.
 */
private DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

public static synchronized DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    // Use the application context, which will ensure that you
    // don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.
    if (db == null) {
        db = new DBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "getInstance()");
    return db;
}


public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);

    this.context = context;
    Log.d(TAG, "DBHelper() Init");

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    try {

        if(dbExist()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DB Exists");
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrade()");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrade: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

}
}
```

I initialize the db like this:

db = DBHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

But for some reason it is not installing the embedded db from Assets.
Any ideas?

Comment: `getInstance(activityname.this)`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya 
Thanks for the reply,i tried what you suggest but it is still doing the same thing.

Comment: @SnakeByte pls refer my post.

Comment: There is no code that copies the file from the assets folder to where it's needed. Anyway, just use [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/).

Answer (score -1):

Here is best way to full fill your need.

Use like this:

```
public class DbAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = DbAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public static Context context;
    public static DataBaseHelper DBHelper;
    public static SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BHMock.sqlite";
    private static final String ASSETS_DATABASE_NAME = "BHMock.sqlite";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    /**
     * This is singleton pattern means : There is one instance of DBHelper in
     * all application : If object created then it will return old instance : If
     * not then create new DBHelper instance
     */
    public DbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;

        if (DBHelper == null) {
            DBHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        }

    }

    /**
     * This is database helper class where all db table is created and
     * drop if there is any update
     */
    public static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private DataBaseHelper(Context mcontext) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/"+DATABASE_NAME;
            } else {
                DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/"+DATABASE_NAME;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate Database");

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            try {

                Log.e(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion
                        + " to " + newVersion);

                // we want both updates, so no break statement here...
                switch (oldVersion) {
                    case 1:

                    case 2:
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        // If database not exists copy it from the assets
        public void CopyAndCreateDataBase() throws IOException {

            boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
            if (!mDataBaseExist) {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                this.getWritableDatabase();
                this.close();
                try {
                    // Copy the database from assests
                    copyDataBase();

                    String mPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME ;

                    Log.v(TAG, "Database created :  " + mPath);

                } catch (IOException mIOException) {
                    throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
                }
            }
        }


        // Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/DatabaseName
        private boolean checkDataBase() {
            File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME);
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
            return dbFile.exists();
        }

        // Copy the database from assets
        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
            InputStream mInput = context.getAssets().open(ASSETS_DATABASE_NAME);
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int mLength;
            while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
                mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
            }
            mOutput.flush();
            mOutput.close();
            mInput.close();
        }

        public static void copyDatabaseToSdCard() {
            try {
                File f1 = new File(DB_PATH);
                if (f1.exists()) {
                    File f2 = new File(Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()
                            + "/" + DATABASE_NAME);
                    f2.createNewFile();
                    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
                    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);
                    byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
                    int len;
                    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                        out.write(buf, 0, len);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {
            if (mDb != null)
                mDb.close();
            super.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);

        }
    }

    // opens the database
    public synchronized SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() throws SQLException {

        if (mDb == null) {
            mDb = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

             Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Database opened");
        }

        return mDb;
    }

    // close the database
    public synchronized void closeDatabase() {

        // db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        // db.endTransaction();
         DBHelper.close();
    }

    public synchronized void exit() {
        try {
            if (DBHelper != null)
                DBHelper = null;

            if (mDb != null) {
                mDb.close();
                mDb = null;
            }
                Log.e(TAG, "dbhelper : " + DBHelper + " Db " + mDb);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And Calling

```
DbAdapter mAdapter = new DbAdapter(this);
```

If you need any help refer this [example](https://github.com/ddpatel2606/AndroidSqliteInsertTime.git)

Comment: Thanks for the reply i, tried your code but some cannot resolve method errors.

     this.getReadableDatabase();
     this.getWriteableDatabase();
     super.close();
     super.open();

Are getting cannot resolve method error.

Answer (score -1):

```
You can use this code, It is working in my app

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class SqlLiteDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb.sqlite";
 private static final String DB_PATH_SUFFIX = "/databases/";
 static Context ctx;
public SqlLiteDbHelper(Context context) {
 super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 ctx = context;
 }
public ArrayList<Contact> getDetails() {
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
 ArrayList<Contact> contList = new ArrayList<>();
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM demo", null);
 if (cursor != null) {
 while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
Contact cont = new Contact(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
 contList.add(cont);
}
 cursor.close();
 db.close();
 }
 return contList;
 }
public void CopyDataBaseFromAsset() throws IOException {
InputStream myInput = ctx.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
// Path to the just created empty db
 String outFileName = getDatabasePath();
// if the path doesn't exist first, create it
 File f = new File(ctx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX);
 if (!f.exists())
 f.mkdir();

// Open the empty db as the output stream
 OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

// transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
 int length;
 while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
 myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
 }
// Close the streams
 myOutput.flush();
 myOutput.close();
 myInput.close();

}
private static String getDatabasePath() {
 return ctx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX
 + DATABASE_NAME;
 }
public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
 File dbFile = ctx.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
if (!dbFile.exists()) {
 try {
 CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
 System.out.println("Copying sucess from Assets folder");
 } catch (IOException e) {
 throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);
 }
 }
return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
 }
@Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}
@Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
 }
}

For more details visit this link
http://androideve.com/2017/02/android-read-sqlite-databse-assets-folder/
```